# react navigation and coordinate measurements

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated, react-animated

react navigation seems to apply some sort of top padding in ios to handle the safe-area,
now if you working with animations it screw up all your calculations especially the ones related to Y coords.

im curious on how you guys work around that using react navigation library? do we have an estimate on how much padding/margin is applied ?

Comment: maybe this helps you out https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#useheaderheight

Comment: oh i didn't know there was a hook for that, thank you !